Getting issue while print in xcode debuger with [ PO ]
(lldb) po companyPageProfileVM.segmentIndex

error: expression failed to parse:
error: virtual filesystem overlay file '/Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyBridge-fdehpisvsuyedxbytdmnccviakbp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/InputBarAccessoryView.build/all-product-headers.yaml' not found
error: virtual filesystem overlay file '/Users/imac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyBridge-fdehpisvsuyedxbytdmnccviakbp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Release-iphonesimulator/InputBarAccessoryView.build/all-product-headers.yaml' not found
error: couldn't IRGen expression. Please check the above error messages for possible root causes.
error: couldn't IRGen expression. Please check the above error messages for possible root causes.
i try This things 
Clean derived data
restart xcode
change output type as well in xcode debugger

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

in this no code available this is just a error message

Try v -o companyPageProfileVM.segmentIndex
